# FFT of a Gaussian; not sure where/how to insert print statements for values

Tags: c++, printf

So, I just started using FFTW pretty recently, and i'm trying it out on a Gaussian curve. Everything compiles fine (when done directly, haven't tried invoking make just yet) but I want it to print my values and i'm not sure where to put these statements in my code; i'm new to working in C/C++ as well. This is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <complex.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "fftw3.h"

    int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
    {

      double complex *in, *out, *data;

      fftw_plan p;

      int i,j;
      int w=20;
      int h=20;
      double a = 2;
      double *x=malloc(i*j*sizeof(double));
      in = (double complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double complex) * w * h);
      out = (double complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double complex) * w * h);
        for(i=0; i<w; i++){
            for(j=0; j<h; j++){
                int temp = i*i+j*j;
                in[i*h+j] = exp(-(temp)/(a*a));
            }
        }
        p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(w, h, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute(p);

        fftw_destroy_plan(p);
        fftw_free(in);
        fftw_free(out);
        return 0;
```

My attempt:

```
    printf("x=[");
        for(i=0; i<w; i++) printf("%15.7g",x[i]);
        printf("];\w\w");

        printf("y=[");
        for(j=0; j<h; j++) printf("%15.7g + %15.7gi", 1./((double) w)*creal(out[i], 1./((double) h)*cimag(out[j]);
        printf("];\h\h");
```

2nd attempt:

```
    printf("x=[");
        for(i=0; i<w; i++) printf("%15.7g",x[i]);
        printf("]");

        printf("y=[");
        for(j=0; j<h; j++) printf("%15.7g + %15.7gi", 1./((double) w)*creal(out[i], 1./((double) h)*cimag(out[j])));
        printf("]");
```

The only error message i'm getting now is that I have too many arguments in        creal

Comment: Not my down-vote, but your expected to have at least *tried* something before coming to SO for help.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in addition to Paul's sentiment, I guess it's because this has more to do with `cout` (or `printf`) than with `fftw`, unless you were asking a theoretical question of some sorts.

Comment: ah ok. I went ahead and removed the fftw tag and edited in some attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your print code anywhere after fftw_execute and before fftw_free.

Note that you have a bug in your allocation of x - you need to use w and h for the size, not i and j. Although on closer inspection x is not even used in your code, so you should probably just get rid of this allocation.

Also note that your code appears to be purely C, not C++ - you should compile it as C and not cast the result of malloc.

Comment: I thought I was using w and h for size? x and y are the values I want to print to after the FFT is performed.

Comment: Look carefully at the malloc call where you allocate memory for `x`.